# Libraries to help port Arduino code to msp430

Tags: arduino, msp430

Does someone know a nice library which makes coding for TI Launchpad MSP430 as easy as for arduino?

So far I only found [Friendly Launchpad](https://github.com/chrishulbert/friendly_launchpad/blob/master/friendly_launchpad.h) and some random code examples.

But I am looking for something that also supports analog readings. Doesn't matter if its doesn't follow the Arduino syntax as long as its simple.

Answer (score 3):

You should check Energia from [their Github page](https://github.com/energia/Energia). It uses the same IDE and language as the Arduino. It is still in development but I tested some basic examples (blink and serial communication) and it works.

Answer (score 2):

I do not believe such a thing exists per se.

It is not a difficult task though to write functions that emulate the Arduino's analogRead() and analogWrite() functions.  I haven't looked at analogue or PWM on the MSP430 yet, so I can't tell you exactly what you need, but the data sheet(s) should point you in the right direction.

Comment: easyMSP, linked below, is pretty much that.  Not quite as easy as arduino, but stepping towards it.  Its got the backing of the 43oh community and is actively being developed.

Answer (score 1):

You may want to try [easyMSP](http://code.google.com/p/easymsp/) I have not used it but have looked at the code and it does have some great functions to make things a bit easyier

Also here is the support site http://www.43oh.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=34&t=1750